# Assign dynamic class in Angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to assign a height class like this:

```
<div class="getScrollViewHeight()">
```

And my method looks like this:

```
getScrollViewHeight(): string {
        return 'h-'+this.scrollViewHeightPercentage;
    }
```

What would be the correct way to do this? And can I use ngClass here?

Comment: if you use class with condition then you can use `ngClass`

For Eg. [ngClass]="{'text-success':true}"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use

```
<div class="{{ 'h-' + scrollViewHeightPercentage }}">
```

As a sidenote, using functions in your template can potentially mean that it is called very often, depending on how often angular has to check for changes. You should avoid calling functions in your template.

Comment: It's fine to call functions in your template, fyi.

Comment: @inorganik functions that do a lot of work can slow down your application considerably, that's why I said you `should` avoid them, if they're not nesscesary. I agree that it would make little to no difference here.

Comment: Using functions in template works but it will affect the performance of your application https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496